Бот тг не реагирует на текст F.text == 'Каталог'
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command

import app.keyboards as kb 

router = Router()


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Привет', reply_markup=kb.main)
    await message.reply('паупау')


@router.message(Command('help'))
async def cmd_help(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Вы нажали на кнопку помощи')


@router.message(F.text == 'Каталог')
async def catalog(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите категорию товара', reply_markup=kb.catalog)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
